# Problem using pantheios file stock back end

Tags: c++, windows, dll, logging, pantheios

I am trying to use pantheios file stock back end to log from my dll in c++. The file gets created but nothing gets written to the file.
Here is a snippet of my code

```
if (pantheios::pantheios_init() < 0)
{    
   MessageBox(NULL, "Init Failed", "fvm", MB_OK);
}else {
   MessageBox(NULL, "Init Passed", "fvm", MB_OK);
   pantheios::log_INFORMATIONAL("Logger enabled!");
}

DWORD pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
sprintf_s(moduleName, sizeof(moduleName), "C:\\%d.log", pid);
pantheios_be_file_setFilePath(moduleName, PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_TRUNCATE,PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_TRUNCATE, PANTHEIOS_BEID_LOCAL);
pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "Entering main");
```

I get the Init Passed message box but no log statements are dumped in the file.

Comment: While I don't know Pantheios, I noticed you are only doing low level logging (info and debug).  Perhaps your configuration is not set to include that detail.  Try logging with `pantheios::log_EMERGENCY()` (the highest level) and see if that shows up.

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the problem. I had tested a demo code using the debug version of my dll and the logging at the default severity level worked fine but in the release build the default severity level is higher.